# Understanding RiscV objdump

Tags: objdump, riscv

I am examining the objdump of a C file that I have compiled using the following commands:

```
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -O0 -o maxmul.o maxmul.c
riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d maxmul.o > maxmul.dump
```

strangely (or not) the addresses appear not to be aligned on 32-bit words but actually on a 16-bit boundary.

Can anyone please explain me why?

Thanks.

objdump excerpt:

```
00000000000101da <main>:
   101da:   7155                    addi    sp,sp,-208
   101dc:   e586                    sd  ra,200(sp)
   101de:   e1a2                    sd  s0,192(sp)
   101e0:   0980                    addi    s0,sp,208
   ...
```

C-code:

```
int main()
{

  int first[3][3], second[3][3], multiply[3][3];
  int golden[3][3];
  int sum;

  first[0][0] = 1;  first[0][1] = 2;  first[0][2] = 3;
  first[1][0] = 4;  first[1][1] = 5;  first[1][2] = 6;
  first[2][0] = 7;  first[2][1] = 8;  first[2][2] = 9;

  second[0][0] = 9;  second[0][1] = 8;  second[0][2] = -7;
  second[1][0] = -6; second[1][1] = 5;  second[1][2] = 4;
  second[2][0] = 3;  second[2][1] = 2;  second[2][2] = -1;

  golden[0][0] = 6;  golden[0][1] = 24;  golden[0][2] = -2;
  golden[1][0] = 24; golden[1][1] = 69;  golden[1][2] = -14;
  golden[2][0] = 42; golden[2][1] = 1140;  golden[2][2] = -26;

  int i, ii, iii;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      for (ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
          for (iii = 0; iii < 3; iii++) {
              //printf("first[%d][%d] * second[%d][%d] \n",  i, iii, iii, ii);
              //printf("%d * %d (%d,%d)\n", first[i][ii], second[ii][i], i, ii);
              sum +=  first[i][iii] * second[iii][ii];
          }
          //printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
          multiply[i][ii] = sum;
          sum = 0;
      }
  }

 int c, d;
 int err;
 for ( c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
      for ( d = 0; d < 3; d++) {
    //printf("%d\t", multiply[c][d]);
          if (multiply[c][d] != golden[c][d]) {
              fail(golden[c][d], multiply[c][d]);
              err++;
          }
      }

      //printf("\n");
    }
    if (err == 0) {
          pass();
      }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When compiling (or assembling) to RV64G**C** or RV32G**C** (or another target that enables the "C" [Standard Extension Compressed Instructions](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-isa-manual)), the compiler (or assembler) automatically replaces some instructions with compressed ones.

Non-compressed instructions are encoded in 32 bit, while compressed instructions are encoded in 16 bit.

When a compressed instruction is emitted it changes the alignment for the next instruction. Either from 32 bit to 16 bit or from 16 bit to 32 bit. That means not only 16 bit wide instructions may be aligned to a 16 bit address but also 32 bit wide ones. IOW both types of instructions (compressed and normal) are tightly packed side by side.

By default, `objdump -d` doesn't explicitly indicate that an instruction is compressed because it uses the same mnemonic as for the uncompressed variant. Although the number of bytes in the displayed raw instruction gives it away (4 vs. 2 bytes).

However, you can tell `objdump` to use separate mnemonics for compressed instructions such that they are more easily recognizable (those start with `c.` then), e.g.:

```
$ riscv64-unknown-elf-objdump -d -M no-aliases rotate
```

```
   [..]
   101e4:       00d66533                or      a0,a2,a3
   101e8:       8082                    c.jr    ra

00000000000101ea <rotr>:
   101ea:       00b55633                srl     a2,a0,a1
   [..]
```

Note that with the switch `-M no-aliases` pseudo-instructions aren't displayed anymore, but the corresponding instruction(s) instead.

Answer (score 8):

I am suspecting that your gcc compiles by default with the compressed instruction format where instructions can be 16b & 32b intermix - in such case, 16b instructions are 16b aligned as you can see in the disassembled code.

Objdump provides the address, the encoding, and the mnemonics ; the encoding in your case is always 16b, which means that the compiler have selected 16b instructions when possible.

By enabling verbose mode (`-verbose`), you can see that, by default,`-march=rv64imafdc` and `-mabi=lp64d`. The default targetted ISA is the compressed one, and the targetted ABI requires Double floats extension.

By setting  `-march=rv64imafd` and letting ABI unchanged, gcc successfully compiles using instructions that are only 32b because compressed ISA is no more enabled.
The addresses of instruction are then always 32b aligned.

Comment: I am getting an error with the suggested option. Any ideas why? cc1: error: requested ABI requires -march to subsume the 'D' extension

Comment: you were right! The gcc was using the compressed instruction format. Thanks for the hint.